# Pandas' `read_sql` creates integer columns when reading from an Oracle table which has number columns with decimal points

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, read-sql

I have a Oracle table with columns of type `VARCHAR2` (i.e. string) and of type `NUMBER` (i.e. a numeric value with a fractional part). And  the numeric columns contain indeed values with decimal points, not integer values.

However when I read this table into a Pandas dataframe via `pandas.read_sql` I receive the numeric columns in the data frame as `int64`. How can I avoid this and receive instead `float` columns with the full decimal values?

I'm using the following versions

```
python           : 3.7.4.final.0
pandas           : 1.0.3
Oracle           : 18c Enterprise Edition / Version 18.9.0.0.0
```

Comment: NUMBER and FLOAT are different data types in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6.

Comment: @pifor True, they are of type NUMBER - adjusting the post accodringly. But they have a decimal fraction and still should not be mapped to integers!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same thing. I am not sure if this is the reason but I assume that `NUMBER` type without any size restrictions is too big for pandas and it is automatically truncated to `int64` or the type is improperly chosen by pandas – default `NUMBER` might be treated as an integer. You can limit the type of the column to e.g. `NUMBER(5,4)` and pandas should recognise it correctly as a float.

I also found out that using `pd.read_sql` gives me proper types in contrast to `pd.read_sql_table`.